# Formik in child component input lost focus when typing

Tags: reactjs, formik

I am trying to put formik into component so i can reuse it.

However, I am having issue that input keep losing focus when I typing the value.
Note that it is working as expected if i don't put the formik form inside component.

What am I doing it wrong?

[Demo here](https://codesandbox.io/s/formik-example-forked-x554gp)

Comment: checkout this [article](https://thewebdev.info/2022/04/24/how-to-fix-input-losing-focus-when-rerendering-with-react/)

Answer (score 1):

```
// Helper styles for demo
import "./helper.css";
import { MoreResources, DisplayFormikState } from "./helper";

import React from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";
import { Formik, useFormik } from "formik";
import * as Yup from "yup";

function App() {
  const postcodeSchema = Yup.object().shape({
    code: Yup.string().required("Postcode is required")
  });

  const postcodeForm = useFormik({
    enableReinitialize: true,
    initialValues: {
      code: ""
    },
    onSubmit: (values) => {
      alert(JSON.stringify(values));
    }
  });

  return (
    <div className="app">
      <FormComponent postcodeForm={postcodeForm} />
    </div>
  );
}

const FormComponent = (props) => {
  const { postcodeForm } = props;
  return (
    <form onSubmit={postcodeForm.handleSubmit}>
      Postcode
      <input
        type="text"
        name="code"
        onChange={postcodeForm.handleChange}
        value={postcodeForm.values.code}
      />
      <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
  );
};
render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

move you function out of the App function.